# Matlab: passing functions as arguments of a function

Tags: matlab, function

The function that I want to build is:

```
function y = myfunction(data, @f1, @f2, @f3, @f4)
%Fit data using f1,f2,f3,f4 such that data ~ af1+bf2+cf3+df4
end
```

where `data` is an array. The user will define `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4` choosing four of the functions `sin(x)`, `cos(x)`, `ln(x)`, `1/x`, `tan(x)`, `tanh(x)`, `1/ln(x)` ... etc.

My aim is to fit `data` a function such that `af1+bf2+cf3+df4`, where `a,b,c,d` are coefficients. The problem is I don't know how to pass functions as inputs and use them inside of `myfunction`. How can I do this? A small example would be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to make them standard arguments, as you would with any other argument

```
function y = myfunction(data, f1, f2, f3, f4)
    % ...
end
```

These arguments are variables of type `function_handle` (so long as you actually pass function handles). To call this function with a set of function handles, you would do

```
f1 = @sin; f2 = @cos; f3 = @ln; f4 = @(x)1/x;
myfunction(data, f1, f2, f3, f4);
```

To create another anonymous function that sums the result of all four, you would do

```
fTotal = @(x)f1(x) + f2(x) + f3(x) + f4(x);
```

Please see [Anonymous Functions](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) for more information.

Comment: Exactly. People get confused about this all of the time. It might help to think of the the `f1`, `f2`, ... as variable names (which they are) as @wakjah suggests and the `@whatever` bits as the values of these variables. Just as with "regular" variables and values you can pass either one into a function, e.g., `var1=1; f1=@sin; f3=@(x)2*x; myfunction(var1, 2, f1, @cos, f3, @(y)y/2)`

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
function y = myfunction(data, f1, f2, f3, f4)
  fprintf('f1(2) = %d\n', f1(2) );
  fprintf('f2(10) = %d\n', f2(10) );
  fprintf('f3(1) = %d\n', f3(1) );
  fprintf('f4(0.1) = %d\n', f4(0.1) );
end

myfunction(@sin, @cos, @ln, @tan);
myfunction(@cos, @sin, @tanh, @ln);
```

I've just made `myfunction` print out some random values as a demonstration.

Note the following:

- To pass the functions into `myfunction`, I used a function handle: `@sin`.
- The arguments to `myfunction` **don't** need the `@` symbol: they are just normal variables.
- Once you have a variable which stores a function handle, you can "call" the variable like it's a function: `f1(x)`

Answer (score 1):

You pass them just as you would any other object.  The '@' is only needed when defining anonymous functions not when they are passed as arguments.

```
function y = myfun1(data, f1);
   y = f1(data);
end

f = @(x)(1./x);
d = 1:4;

disp( myfun1(d, f) );
```

will give you

> ```
> 1.0000    0.5000    0.3333    0.2500
> ```

and extending this to more functions is straightforward.